# Can't find any CoAP implementation for Chaos Calmer

Tags: openwrt

I'd like to know why isn't there any Coap package for OpenWRT's Chaos Calmer.

Almost every OpenWRT distribution has libcoap in its package list, but Chaos Calmer doesn't have it.

https://archive.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/

Is there any limitation?

Best regards,

H.H.